Calculating the Characteristic Function of a Random Variable for the number of samples till the sum is greater than or equal to some value
I have some known random variable, X, with strictly non-negative support. I have a value $n$ to sum to. I want to calculate the closed form of one of the functions (PDF, CDF, MGF, CF, or PGF), in terms of known $X$ and $n$, of the random variable $Z_n$, which is the number of times X must be sampled for the sum of samples to be greater than or equal to $n$.
Effectively I have a biased dice with 0 through some value on its sides, and I'm rolling it until the sum of all the rolls I've done so far reaches or exceeds $n$. $Z_n$ is the random variable of the number of rolls needed.
My idea so far:
Let $Y_r$ be a random variable that is the resulting sum of sampling $X$ $r$ times. $Y_r$ is a convolution and it's MGF, CF, or PGF can be easily calculated as a power of $X$ respective function.
For random variable $Z_n$ to be equal to $r$, we must first have a sum $< n$ at $r-1$ samples, and then after sampling the additional time we must have a sum $\geq n$. This can be expressed as:
$$P(Z_n=r) = \sum_{j=1}^mP(X=j)\sum_{k=1}^jP(Y_{r-1}=n-k)$$
At this point I'm lost. How do I prove the $Z_n$ defined here is a probability (sums to 1)? Multiplying the two probabilities on the right side is hard because I'm not guaranteed to be able to find a nice (without a integral) representation of $P(Y_r=?)$, and converting both to the MGF, CF, or PGF (and therefor calculating the MGC, CF, or PGF of $Z_n$) would turn the multiplication into a convolution. The two summations make it look like some sort of partial convolution through?
